# Упал веб-сервер Apache2 и вместе с ним сайт

Tags: php, apache

Упал веб-сервер Apache2 и вместе с ним сайт. При команде sudo service apache2 start выдает: Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. При journalctl -xe, выдает что файлы не найдены. Состояние сервера:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-10-31 10:42:55 UTC; 2min 6s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 356793 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

. Как мне сделать файлы для журналов? как поднять заново сервер Apache?
Текст ошибки: No journal files were found. -- No entries --

Comment: ubuntu используется

Comment: текст ошибки (про ненайденные файлы) всё-таки приведите (нажав [edit])

Comment: No journal files were found. -- No entries --

Comment: Так может консоль не врет, и вам действительно дропнули файлы на сервере ? Зайти по ftp по указанному адресу и посмотреть наличие файлов в директории.

Comment: да нет, я всегда с ftp работал, все файлы на месте

Comment: `journalctl | tail` что говорит?

Comment: уже мне неизвестно, я переустановил apache, все заработало, но теперь я не могу подключиться к бд mysql (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')

Comment: `sudo find / -type s` покажет список сокетов, mysqld.sock там есть? если не работает то разверните слэш, не помню в какую сторону он должен быть